# Isotope items overlap on initial load

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

Using a masonry layout for [this site](http://mtthwbsh.com/sta499) and upon the first load each box overlaps. If you use any of the navigational items to sort or even just stay on "all" they rearrange themselves. Any ideas?

Comment: I just answered my own question! For anyone who stumbled upon this, just make sure you wrap your isotope script in $(window).load

Comment: Awesome! Just fixed my issue as well. Thanks!

Comment: The first question in the FAQs of masonry ("How do I fix overlapping items?") - http://masonry.desandro.com/faq.html - also highlights that you can use the `imagesLoaded` function.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a reputation of 50 yet so I can't comment, but I wanted to share a couple tips that I stumbled upon in the past as I've used this plugin a lot, and it could help other people.

First off, I definitely use the imageLoaded function as Sarah mentioned, and not the onload. (https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded)

Tip 1 - 
To speed up the isotope plugin getting to work (useful if image sizes are big, or you have a lot of them), you load a placeholder image for each container, then after the imagesloaded plugin fires, you can have the isotope plugin get to work quickly. Then you can swap the real image in with a data- attribute that contains the real src url, just do so using the isotope callback (http://isotope.metafizzy.co/events.html). The only caveot is your images would need to have the same dimensions as the placeholder or the sizing of the containers could get messed up and overlap again.

Tip 2 -
I never actually did this, but one method I was thinking of using was to load the images as a background image of the container, set a height and with for the container (or at least the image part of it), set the images as background-size: cover; and then you don't need to worry about the images loading before the isotope plugin can get to work.